# Is it possible with flow-type to typecheck for simple types such as a uri

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

Say, I have a function that takes a string, and makes sure it's a valid uri:

```
function checkUri(input: string): Uri {

}
```

Is it possible to define this new type `Uri` in a way that it can only ever be emitted by this checkUri method, even though I really just want it to be a string?

My end goal is that I want to define a bunch of types that have `Uri` properties, and I want to enforce validation through my type system.

So from the outside the `Uri` type looks and behaves like an immutable string that's guaranteed to have been validated.

Comment: I believe you can use [`opauq types`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/) for this very reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment (in which is misspelled [`opaque`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/)), [here's an try flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEB7ADlAjgVwQFwJ7IQFUYBLALngGdtSA7AcwChHRJYEAzDWsbExWvDAALcAGtiJABQlayDNgrU69AJQVJzVtDjwuPPgPj1EAFUSSpGUhtLr4AN0QlgzMAOrxrJeAF4homASpFIA5MARwKGqbh7YVIgAtiAAyjSy9H7w4ZGhzAD0+fAAJACiAB4EvKUwMIgwjCbmlpRJqekMMY1mFiHeqkA):

```
// declaring in the try makes it act as if it were imported, but I'll just import here
import { checkUri, type Uri } from 'some-file';

function useUri(uri: Uri): void {}

// $ExpectError
useUri('some string')

// this one works
useUri(checkUri('some string'))
```